# Visual Studio 2017 "use of undefined type"

Tags: c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I have the following code which fails to compile with Visual Studio 2017 with error

> Error [C2027](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2027?view=vs-2017) use of undefined type 'A'

but is compiling fine in Visual Studio 2012 & Visual Studio 2015.

```
#include <iostream>

    class A;
    std::string s = typeid(A).name();

    class A
    {
        public:
           int a;
    };

    int main()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
    }
```

Can anyone suggest what exactly is the problem with VS 2017 compilation and how to fix this?
Is there any rule changes between VS 2015 and VS 2017?

Comment: "_The header `<typeinfo>` must be included before using `typeid` (if the header is not included, every use of the keyword `typeid` makes the program ill-formed.)_" - [typeid](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)

Comment: When asking questions about build errors, please copy-paste (as text) the *full* and *complete* error output into the question. *What* type is "undefined"? Please read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: "_C2027 - A type cannot be used until it is defined. To resolve the error, be sure the type is fully defined before referencing it._"

Answer (score 2):

The errors I get from clang and gcc for this example are more clear:

```
typeid.cpp:5:17: error: 'typeid' of incomplete type 'A'
std::string s = typeid(A).name();
                ^
typeid.cpp:4:7: note: forward declaration of 'A'
class A;
```

`class A` is a forward declaration of the `A` type, so the full information about that type is not yet known.  I suspect behavior of Visual Studio 2012 and 2015 would be considered non-standard.  You need to move your string until after the definition `class A {...};` so the compiler can see the type definition.